# How to create Google Action using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, actions-on-google, npm-scripts

New to Google Actions development. How can I create new Google action using node.js? I know how to accomplish this using Dialogflow. How can I create that app.js file of Google Action?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you start with the [Actions on Google codelab 1](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-1/#0) in order to learn more about building a Node.js webhook for an Action.